# Looking for DB replicator (like C-JDBC, HA-JDBC etc.)

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, replication, activemq-classic, database-replication

I need to replicate my DB without adding it any columns (like the MS SQL replication does), I looked every where and every project I found was last updated 2-3 years ago (in the best case i found a project last version was from 2011).

The replicator needs to support MS SQL 2005 (2008 is not required now) over JDBC driver and it's also preferred that the project is still active and updated (bug fixing, features requests, support etc.)

if any one knows any replicator with these characteristics please help me !

just to be clear, the DB replicated is a MS SQL created by ActiveMQ 5.5.1 using Microsoft JDBC driver 3.0

Comment: Your choice of target will influence the choice here.  That is, what does it need to replicate *to*?

Comment: The replicated DB is also MS SQL.
the replication can't be the MS SQL replication and also can't create MS SQL cluster using Microsoft Products

Comment: My question would be: why not use SQL replication?  What feature is it lacking?  Right now, you just have an arbitrary requirement that is going to be non-trivial to solve for.

Comment: The SQL replication add the replication ID column for each table which interferes with ActiveMQ operation.
The other solution, from Microsoft, is SQL Cluster which I thought about but seems like I can't use it according to higher requirements from the whole system architecture.

Comment: That's not true.  Merge replication adds a timestamp column, but the only requirement to replicate a table via transactional replication is that the table has a primary key.  If you're using transactional replication, it doesn't add any columns to your table.

Comment: Also, clustering does not allow you to have a second place to read your data from.  It protects you from failure of a physical server.

Comment: Regarding the DB Cluster that is only backup - It's possible to do a fail-over to the clustered DB if the main Server is down.
 but for the comment about transactional replication - it's new for me and it seems like it's a good solution to my problem. I'll update here after I'll check it after the weekend.

Comment: The "weekend" is over ... any update?